# Subversion checkout error when checking out repository with &

Tags: svn, special-characters, checkout

My Subversion repository name has `&` in it. I get an error while checking it out. Is there a workaround?

```
svn co https://ssss.my.com/D&G/
OPTIONS of https://ssss.my.com/D&G/ 200 OK
```

Comment: Try using `\&` instead of `&`

Comment: I tried all options %26, &#38; &amp; and \& as you suggest. \& returns could not open the requested file system. I wonder if this is something with my apache config.

Comment: Do you own and control the repository? Are there other users, or just you? If you are the only user then concider changing the name of the repository. Say: `https://ssss.my.com/DnG/`

Comment: For file protocol `svn info "file:///d:/repo/D&G"` is working fine. Try to `svn info "https://ssss.my.com/D&G/"`

Comment: `svn info "https://ssss.my.com/D&G/"` does not work for me. what's your version of svn client?

Comment: i tried only file:// now, and i'll try https// later. svn is 1.8

Comment: I could not create the D&G repo with Visual SVN Server. Do you have the published one?

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostil suggested in a comment what you need to do is "escape" the `&` character.  SVN usually supports [%-codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in URLS, from experience urls containing spaces will get converted to %20 characters.

The %-code for `&` (ampersand) is %26 so try the command:

```
svn co https://ssss.my.com/D%26G/
```

Comment: %20 works for spaces but not %26

Answer (score 0):

Do you own and control the repository? Are there other users, or just you? If you are the only user then concider changing the name of the repository. Say: `https://ssss.my.com/DnG/`

Alternatively:

```
ssh root@ssss.my.com

### Just trying to make it explicit that you need to cd to the directory above "D&G"
cd /path/to/svn/repository/D\&G/ && cd ..

ln -s D/&G DnG

### Now, if necessary, edit your apache configuration so that the DnG softlink gets served up to https://ssss.my.com/DnG/
```

Comment: yes, I own svn and can change it but it is linked to so many other systems that refer to D&G. the links break. I put in a process so new repositories dont have characters like & but need to get to the bottom of why svn co does not like &

Comment: Does the `&` break things on all of those other systems configured to use `D&G`? If not, and you are only having trouble doing a local checkout, then my solution will still work around your issue. Since you are just creating a symbolic link that points `DnG` --> `D&G`, your other systems can still continue to use `D&G` while you use `DnG`. Both point at the same repository, so it won't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the official doc for repository naming conventions, but all tested http(s) svn servers allow only alpha, nums, dash and underscore chars in repo name.

I think using of & char in repo name is incorrect.

But you can use the & in folders path in your repo.

Answer (score -2):

The usage of '%26' instead of special character '&' solves the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Your post doesn't appear to address the question in a useful manner.  This is an old post with various answers and one of those proposed the same answer as you and it didn't work .  You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the SuperUser [tour] and review site guidelines on [ask] and [answer].  If you follow the norms of the SuperUser community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: I do not think it is that simple. It is best to avoid special characters instead.